# node.js What is the correct way to parse/join URLs?

Tags: node.js, urlencode

If I have a URL like this:

```
> u = 'http://examples.com/hello world/test'
'http://examples.com/hello world/test'
```

and parse it into components using built-in `URL` object in node.js, it gets automatically url-encoded:

```
> uObj = new URL(u)
URL {
  href: 'http://examples.com/hello%20world/test',
  origin: 'http://examples.com',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'examples.com',
  hostname: 'examples.com',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/hello%20world/test',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: ''
}
```

Now I can, for example, conveniently change some properties.

The problem is that if I later convert it back to URL-string with `uObj.toString()` it stays url-encoded!

```
> uObj.toString()
http://examples.com/hello%20world/test
```

Then I pass this string further to another library/function which expects raw url on the input and thus encodes it again.

```
http://examples.com/hello%25%20world/test
```

(note how `%` was escaped to `%25`).

[According to MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#encoding_for_rfc3986), even build-in `encodeURI()` doesn't handle all possible situations according to latest RFCs, so I'm not sure if `decodeURI()` works correctly? Can I just use `decodeURI(uObj.toString())` and sleep peacefully? Or I should be using some npm module here?

Comment: What problem does the additional encoding actually cause? If someone expects an encoded string, they should know when to decode it. What goes wrong in your case?

Comment: Since I get encoded URL back from `.toString()`, if I later use this url in other libraries/functions they end up trying to access non-existent resource. I need to somehow reliably get raw url back from new URL()

Answer (score 0):

The space (SP, U+0020) character in your URL gets (and stays) encoded because that character is not allowed in the path component of the URL. Per [RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), the only characters allowed in a *path segment* are

- US-ASCII letters: `A`-`Z` and `a`-`z`
- US-ASCII decimal digits: `0`-`9`
- `-`, `.`, `_`, `~`
- Subdelimiters: `!`, `$`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `;`, `=`

with the path itself allowing `/` as segment separators.

Anything else *must* be percent-encoded.

Comment: Thank you! Does it work correctly though `new URL('http://example.com/hello[world]/1.png?x=test test').toString()` produces `http://example.com/hello[world]/1.png?x=test%20test` (square brackets are not encoded)

Comment: Hm, `decodeURI` seem to work fine in any case (both if I encode `[]` and if I don't). So it's probably the solution to my initial question. It's still really confusing that `new URL(...).toString()` produces incorrect result, though. If I'm not mistaken here